# Condition not checking after adding error condition in postman

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest, apexrest

I have created apex class to update existing records, and I am adding error code, but record is updating when I run it in postman. But if I miss any parameters, I have to show error which is given in class, but it's not checking if condition.
instead of given error it showing below error:

> [
> {
> "errorCode": "APEX_ERROR",
> "message": "System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
> Class.LeadSharingClass.getleads: line 14, column 1"
> }
> ]

here is my apex class:

```java
@RestResource(urlMapping='/UpdateLead/*')
global with sharing class LeadSharingClass {
    @HttpPut
    global static void getleads(string Salutation,string FirstName,string LastName){
        RestRequest leadrequest = RestContext.request;
        try{
            Map<String, String> leadRequestParams =leadrequest.params;
            //Integer leadlimit = Integer.val
                leads.Salutation=Salutation==null ? leads.Salutation : Salutation;
                leads.FirstName=FirstName == null ? leads.FirstName : FirstName;
                leads.LastName=LastName==null ? leads.LastName : LastName;
                update leads;
                RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(leads));
                RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            }
        }
        catch(System.StringException e){
            RestContext.response.statusCode = 400;
            SalesforceError[] errs = new SalesforceError[]{ 
                new SalesforceError('BAD_REQUEST', 'Param: leadId is not a valid Id')
                    };
                        RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(errs));
        }
    }
    global class SalesforceError {
        public String errorCode;
        public String message;
        // public String statusCode;
        public SalesforceError(String errorCode, string message){
            // this.statusCode=statusCode;
            this.errorCode = errorCode;
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should re-arrange your code so that you're checking for missing parameters *before you use those parameters*.

That's the approach for code *in general*. If you're going to check something, you check it before you use it.

Comment: could you please share me sample code or modified code above code, i am new to apex and integration

Comment: @user116229 This is a simple operation where you're only moving some existing lines of code around. I need to see you make an honest attempt at this. If you are unable to do this without someone giving you a copy-paste answer, then you need to dedicate some time to practicing fundamentals of programming.

Comment: In other words, you need to try to do it yourself. You can come back and edit your question to add additional information (I modified my code to `new code block`, and now I'm getting error `error message`). Don't immediately give up if you hit an error though; try to search for the error message and try to understand why the error is happening. Struggle with it for a while (say, 30 minutes to an hour) before asking for help.

Comment: Thank you, i have tried and made the changes accordingly, now i am getting error message and i have uploaded the updated code here.